What's the the LO-IF feedthrough with the presence only of the gate-drain capacitance \$C_{GD}\$?
Shown below is the front-end of a 1.8-GHz receiver. The LO frequency is chosen to be 900 MHz
and the load inductors and capacitances resonate with a quality factor Q at IF. Assume 1 is biased
at a current \$_1\$, and the mixer and LO are perfectly symmetric. Also assume 2 and 3 are ideal
switches (they switch abruptly and completely). Compute


(a) the measured level of the 900-MHz
at the output in the absence of an RF signal.
$$I^+_{IF} = \biggl(I_{DC} + V_{RF} g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t) \biggl) \biggl(\frac{1} {2} + \frac{2} {\pi}\biggl)$$
$$I^-_{IF} = \biggl(I_{DC} + V_{RF} g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t) \biggl) \biggl(\frac{1} {2} - \frac{2} {\pi}\biggl)$$
$$V_{IF} = V^+_{IF} - V^-_{IF}$$
$$\Rightarrow V_{IF} = \frac{s R_p L_p} {R_p + s L_p} \bigl(I^+_{IF} - I^-_{IF}\bigl)$$
$$\Rightarrow V_{IF} = \frac{s R_p L_p} {R_p + s L_p} \biggl(I_{DC} + V_{RF} g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t) \biggl) \frac{4} {\pi}$$

(b) the LO-IF feedthrough with the presence only of
the gate-drain capacitance \$_{}\$. Neglect gate-source and gate-bulk capacitance.

$$V^+_{LO}\ g_{m2} = \bigl(V_x - V^+_{LO}\bigl) s C_{GD} - \frac{V_x} {R_p} - \frac{V_x} {s L_p}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_x} {V^+_{LO}} = \frac{g_{m2} + s C_{GD}} {s C_{GD} - 1/R_D - 1/L_P} $$
$$V^+_{LO}\ g_{m2} =  V_{RF}\ g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t)$$
$$V_x = \frac{ V_{RF}\ g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t) } { g_{m2} } \frac{g_{m2} + s C_{GD}} {s C_{GD} - 1/R_D - 1/L_P}$$
$$V^+_{IF} = \frac{ V_{RF}\ g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t) } { g_{m2} } \frac{g_{m2} + s C_{GD}} {s C_{GD} - 1/R_D - 1/L_P} \biggl(\frac{1} {2} + \frac{2} {\pi}\biggl)$$
Similarly for the right part which consists of M3, \$L_p\$ and \$R_p\$
$$V^-_{IF} = \frac{ V_{RF}\ g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t) } { g_{m3} } \frac{g_{m3} + s C_{GD}} {s C_{GD} - 1/R_D - 1/L_P} \biggl(\frac{1} {2} - \frac{2} {\pi}\biggl)$$
Since we know this is matched mixer, which means M2 and M3 are the same
$$\Rightarrow g_{m2} = g_{m3}$$
$$V_{IF} = V^+_{IF}  - V^-_{IF} $$
$$V_{IF} = \frac{ V_{RF}\ g_{m1} \cos (\omega_{RF} t) } { g_{m2} } \frac{g_{m2} + s C_{GD}} {s C_{GD} - 1/R_D - 1/L_P} \biggl(\frac{4} {\pi}\biggl)$$
Are my answer for question a and b  correct?


(a) Single-ended with LO-IF feedthrough (b) transformation from parallel to series
From Fig. 3.2 (b), the presence of \$V_{LO}^{+}\$ at node \$V_x\$ can be derived by the following expressions,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{V^{+}_{LO} - V_x}{Z_C} &= \frac{V_x}{Z_L + R_S} \\
\Rightarrow V_x \left[ \frac{Z_C + Z_L + R_S}{(Z_L + R_S) Z_C} \right] &= \frac{V^{+}_{LO}}{Z_C} \\
\Rightarrow V_x &= \frac{V^{+}_{LO}(Z_L + R_S)}{Z_C + Z_L + R_S} \tag{3.1}
\end{align}
$$
Notice that the \$V_{DD}\$ is an RF ground and the voltage \$V_{LO}^{+}\$ is a train of rectangular pulses. The \$V_{LO}^{+}\$ representation in the time domain is expressed from the Fourier series as
$$
\begin{equation}
V_{LO}^{+} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \text{sinc}\left(\frac{k \pi}{2}\right) \cos\left(k \omega_{LO} t - \frac{k \pi}{2}\right)
\tag{3.2}
\end{equation}
$$
Since we are interested in the frequency component at \$\omega_{LO}\$, we work with \$k = 1\$. Then, substituting (3.2) into (3.1), the LO-IF feedthrough can be expressed as,
$$
V_x = \frac{(Z_L + R_S)}{Z_C + Z_L + R_S} \left[\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \cos\left(\omega_{LO} t - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]
$$
$$
V_x = \frac{(Z_L + R_S)}{Z_C + Z_L + R_S} \left[\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sin(\omega_{LO} t)\right]
\tag{3.3}
$$
Carrying out the same analysis, but for \$V_{LO}^{-}\$ with \$k = 1\$, we have
$$
V_{LO}^{-} \big|_{k=1} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi} \sin(\omega_{LO} t)
\tag{3.4}
$$
Therefore, the LO-IF feedthrough in the other section of the circuit, \$V_y\$, equals
$$
V_y = \frac{(Z_L + R_S)}{Z_C + Z_L + R_S} \left[\frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi} \sin(\omega_{LO} t)\right]
\tag{3.5}
$$
Finally, the differential voltage \$V_x - V_y\$, corresponding to the total contribution of the LO-IF feedthrough, is expressed as
$$
V_x - V_y = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{(Z_L + R_S)}{(Z_C + Z_L + R_S)} \sin(\omega_{LO} t) \hspace{5mm} \blacksquare
\tag{3.6}
$$

Your answer seems to follow a logical path. However, certain assumptions here were not even mentioned in the original question. I suggest editing the original question with assumptions about the LO waveform, etc. Then, this answer is acceptable and correct. As for the load, I do not know what your question is asking for. However, in my opinion, the inductor should be resonated out since $\omega_{IF} = \omega_{LO}$. This only simplifies your final equation, it does not change it.

Your answer for part (a) seems incorrect. In the absence of RF signals, the LO feedthrough would be calculated, not the RF signal down-conversion, as you have shown. In other words, you must set \$V_{RF} = 0\$. Then, the LO waveform would simply steer the bias current to either output. Furthermore, given the assumptions of the question and since \$\omega_{IF} = \omega_{LO}\$ you can simplify the tank to be just \$R_P\$ at \$\omega_{IF}\$.
For part (b), looks like the feedthrough due to \$C_{GD}\$ only is required, which probably means ignoring the \$g_m\$ term. Note that without this simplification, \$g_m\$ terms are still invalid for large-signal operations! To continue, I would again set \$V_{RF} = 0\$ since for small signal RF inputs the LO feedthrough would be completely independent of the RF input. Then, you can again simplify the tank to be just \$R_P\$ at \$\omega_{IF} = \omega_{LO}\$ and use a voltage divider between \$C_{GD}\$ and \$R_P\$ to determine the approximate feedthrough:
$$\frac{V_{x}}{V_{LO}^{+}} \approx \frac{sR_P C_{GD}}{1 + sR_P C_{GD}}\,.$$

Could you write the equation in details in each answer?

If $V_{RF} = 0$ , the current through M1 for small signal analysis will be 0. Only DC $I_{DC}$ current is remained.

@kile that is correct. With no RF input, the only waveform at the output will be due to the LO leakage. This is a well-known characteristic of the single-balanced mixer. The LO is steering the DC bias current, generating a peak differential current of $I_{DC}\cdot 4/\pi$ at $\omega_{LO} = \omega_{IF}$ at the output. In other words, without the RF input, you are simply buffering the LO with a differential pair!

In my opinion,  $$\frac{V_x} {R_p} + \frac{V_x} {s L_p} = \biggl(V^+{LO} - V_x\biggl) s C{GD}$$
This is for part b

@kile which, given the question's statement "the load inductors and capacitances resonate with a quality factor Q at IF," reduces to what I suggested at $ s = j\omega_{IF}$.

If the load inductors and capacitances resonate, shouldn't they be cancelled out?
Can you write KCL and KVL equation in its original form?

@kile they do cancel out, and the remnant is $R_P$. Well, to be strict, if $R_P$ does not model the loss of the inductor, then $R_{eq} = R_P \Vert Q\omega_{IF}L_P$ because of the finite quality of the inductor.

Can you write how you can cancel out those C and L at resonate frequency?

@kile standard parallel admittance equations: $Y_{eq} = j\omega_{IF}C_L + 1/j\omega_{IF}L_P$ which is zero if $\omega_{IF} = 1/\sqrt{L_PC_L}$, with $C_L$ being the total load capacitance at the output.

In my opinion, $C_{GD}$ and $L_p$ are in series, Where did you find $C_L$? I don't $C_L$ should exitst according to the question.

It seemed that you ignored $R_p$ which is in parallel to $L_p$ for equivalent admittance. Is $C_L$ the cap between $V^+_{IF}$ and ground?

@kile $C_L$ is your output load capacitance, which the question assumes is resonated out with $L_P$. You do not need to include $R_P$ to show this resonance; $R_P$ is the remnant of the tank after resonance. $C_{GD}$ is ignored in the resonance equation since typically it is small. However, for leakage analysis, you assume a voltage divider between $C_{GD}$ and $R_P$. This is the standard error analysis method. You cannot elegantly deal with everything at once.

Can you take a look at my answer given by my teacher?
